# Can you clear my this confusion between "no" and "not"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, negation, comparative-constructions

I have seen sentences like:

> They ask for money no less than Rs 2,000.
>
> He was looking weird? No weirder than usual.

I wonder should "not" had been in place of "no". Are they interchangeable?

Comment: See here: [dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/no-or-not](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/no-or-not).

Comment: @user2684291 - Although that page says "*no* before a noun phrase; *not* everywhere else", and I'm not sure that "weirder than usual" is a noun phrase.

Comment: @stangdon: I don't think that observation in Cambridge Dictionary has any particular relevance to ***comparatives*** such as *He's **not/no** taller than me*. Offhand it seems to me the choice there is entirely a matter of syntactic / stylistic preference. In *most* cases, at least, but I'd be interested to see if anyone can come up with contexts for each form where the other one is either non-idiomatic or has a different meaning.

Comment: The first sentence is not grammatical. This is grammatical: They ask for no less than 2,000 rupees OR They ask for not less than 2,000 rupees. I wrote it out so you can see the noun rupees.

Answer (score 1):

*Not* is used to negate verbs.

> I did not walk away.
>
> He is not stupid.
>
> Take whichever one is not broken.
>
> I have not been walking recently.
>
> Do not go there.

Also, *not* negates a verbal, entire noun phrase, or *anyone*/*everyone* if it's a subject of a sentence.

> Not walking regularly has made me unhealthy.
>
> Not that I really care but can you tell me why she left?
>
> I decided not to go to the park.
>
> Not just anyone will do this job for what I'm paying.

*No* is used elsewhere.  So in "He was looking weird? No weirder than usual" you are right to use the *no*.

Comment: Not weirder than usual. It sounds also correct to me.

Comment: I think because "[It is || he looks ] not weirder than usual" is conversationally elided.  Which may also apply to my "Not just anyone ..." example above.